# How do I get the start and end character indices of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to figure out how to get the range of characters affected by an element in an overall HTML document using JavaScript. **I only need webkit compatible code.**

I'm thinking I'm just not searching for the right terms?

Here is an example of what I'll be working with:

```
<body>
This is the way we 
<span class="highlight"><img src="image.png" />
search the <span class="heavy">text</span>
</span>, 
search the text, search the text, 
early in the morning!
</body>
```

If I get a reference to the span with the class highlight...
I want to know the start and end index of the characters that the highlight span contains, including the text in it's child spans, but, of course, NOT the characters that are part of the element declarations themselves, such as "<", ">" or anything between them.

Comment: What do you mean by "start and end index?" What are you trying to accomplish here? Whatever it is, this does not sound like the right approach.

Comment: This is non-trivial, but I think you'd want to build a depth-first traversal of *just* the text nodes, and then figure it out from that. Of course, that won't take into account the effects of CSS on the *apparent* index of some particular text element.

Comment: @Pointy: You can use a Range to avoid the complexity of that approach, but your caveat still applies.

Comment: @TimDown well yes you're right; I guess that's effectively what a Range would do :-)  But I don't think that would take into account hidden elements, floats, etc, right?

Comment: @Pointy: No, you're right. I've spent quite a bit of effort on this problem: https://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/TextRangeModule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a [DOM Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range). This approach is not perfect: offsets will include white space text nodes, text nodes within script elements and text in elements that are hidden by CSS, and will not include line breaks implied by block elements and `<br>` elements, but may be good enough for your requirements.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/QhNZ6/

Code:

```
function getOffsetWithinBodyText(node) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(document.body);
    range.setEndBefore(node);
    var start = range.toString().length;

    return {
        start: start,
        end: start + node.textContent.length
    };
}
```

Comment: BINGO! Thank you! :D I wanted to make sure this didn't change the selection, and it doesn't! You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/QhNZ6/4/

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to grab that text:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".highlight")[0].innerText
```